# Extracting consecutive string after a particular string in regex python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a column in pandas dataframe which contains incomplete JSON array like data.
For ex first row of that column is like **[{"name":"A","type":"Food","service":"xyz_abc"},{"name":"B","type":"drinks","service":"pqr_ghi"},{"name":"C","type"**

I want to extract the values **xyz_abc** and **pqr_ghi** given after service in data.
How can I do this using regex in python?

Comment: If it's in json then you can try `df['column_name'].apply(lambda x:[y['service'] for y in x])` and if its of type `string` then this code throws you an error

Comment: Is the single quote behind "drinks" a typo? Also, have you tried/researched something that you can include in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

df['service'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'(?<=service")\s*:\s*"(.+?)"', x))
```

```
print(df)

                                                 col             service
0  [{"name":"A","type":"Food","service":"xyz_abc"...  [xyz_abc, pqr_ghi]
```